# How to use backend on google colab

Tags: keras, localhost, google-colaboratory

Google Colab is quite a pleasant place to do coding. But there are some problems I'm bugged.

I'm trying to output the intermediate results in a trained neural network using keras backend with the following code I found,

```
from keras import backend as K

inp = model.input                                           # input placeholder
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]          # all layer outputs
functors = [K.function([inp]+ [K.learning_phase()], [out]) for out in outputs]  # evaluation functions

# Testing
test = np.random.random(input_shape)[np.newaxis,...]
layer_outs = [func([test, 1.]) for func in functors]
print layer_outs
```

It worked fine to make up the functions. However, when the function is called, it's reporting the following error,

```
FailedPreconditionErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-f0000c1b16a6> in <module>()
----> 1 layer_outs = [func([X_test]) for func in functors]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in __call__(self, inputs)
   2480         session = get_session()
   2481         updated = session.run(fetches=fetches, feed_dict=feed_dict,
-> 2482                               **self.session_kwargs)
   2483         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2484 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1134       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1136     else:
   1137       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1314     if handle is None:
   1315       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1316                            run_metadata)
   1317     else:
   1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333         except KeyError:
   1334           pass
-> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1336 
   1337   def _extend_graph(self):

FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable dense_1/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense_1/kernel)
     [[Node: dense_1/MatMul/ReadVariableOp = ReadVariableOp[dtype=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](dense_1/kernel)]]
     [[Node: dense_1/Relu/_3 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_14_dense_1/Relu", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

It seems that my neural network is saved locally, and thus the variables cannot be called from the remote backend on Google Colab. I'm not sure if that's the case, and how could I solve the problem.

The code worked perfectly on my mac. But managing to make it work on Google Colab seems to be more pleasant for future.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are a number of approaches that may work for you. I found it best to mount my google drive from colab. That way it is easy to load and save files.

```
try:
    from google.colab import drive
except ModuleNotFoundError as colab_not_found:
    raise ModuleNotFoundError('Only run this cell on google colab!') from colab_not_found

# This will prompt for authorization.
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```